# How to calculate how far out a special character is in a string JAVA

Tags: java, string

My assignment in an introductory level course is as follows:

In computers the * character is often used to represent wildcard characters that may be substituted for any set of characters. For instance, if you search a file directory for *.txt your computer returns a list of all files in the directory with the .txt extension.

For this assignment you will input a String that contains a single * character, then a second String. The * will be replaced by the second String. So for example, if the user enters the Strings `"d*g"` and `"in"`, the program outputs `ding`.

The original String must contain only letters of the alphabet, capital or lowercase, spaces and tab, and a single `*`. Any additional `*`'s can count be treated as an invalid characters. The replacement String may be any legal String in Java.

If the first String does not contain a `*` "`Error: no *"` should be output.
If the first String contains anything other than letters of the alphabet, spaces or tabs then `"Error: Incorrect characters"` should be printed. If the first String does not have a `*` you do not have to check for incorrect characters, only `"Error: no *"` should be output.

**Sample Run 1**

```
Enter the first String:
D*g

Enter the replacement String:
in

Ding
```

**Sample Run 2**

```
Enter the first String:
$Wild*$

Enter the replacement String:
Card

Error: Incorrect characters
```

I started with :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;


class Lesson_22_Activity_Two {
    public static String [] list = {};
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first String:");
        String x1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");
        String x2 = scan.nextLine();

    }
}
```

I am however stuck on how to calculate how far out the `*` is.

If I could get that value I could print the first n letters of x1, then x2, then the rest of x1. Any help on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `String.contains` and `String.replace`?

Comment: String.indexOf("#") ?

Comment: I guess you mean `*` instead of `#`

Answer (score 0):

to get the index of a character in a string....

```
int index = yourstring.indexOf('yourcharacter')
```

then relocate that character in the string using:

```
 Char yourchar = charAt(index)
```

or use charAt(index) as a parameter in another method to denote where your special character is

to insert the new string into the old string use substring():

```
  String x1 = "D*g";
  String x2 = "in";
```

now split up x1 into the part before the * and the part after

```
  String x3 = x1.substring(0 , x1.indexOf("*")); //start at 0, end at index of *
  String x4 = x1.substring(x1.indexOf("*")+1); // start at index of * +1(after the *), no end needed
  String output = x3 + x2 + x4; //concatenate your strings together
  System.out.println(output); //This will output Ding to the cli
```

By the end of this:

x3 will contain D

x4 will contain g

output will contain the string Ding

Answer (score 0):

```
x1.indexOf("#");
```

If this value is not -1 then that means that '#' is in the string and gives you the index of the character, bearing in mind that the index starts at 0.

If you want to use an if statement to run code only if a special character is in a string use:

```
if(x1.indexOf("#")!=-1){
    // code
}
```